# Disable atmospheric drag in smoke simulator?

Tags: animation, physics, fluid-simulation, smoke-simulation

I know this is a stretch, but using the smoke simulator, I'd like to simulate a gas moving through a vacuum (space) which means that the gas should not be slowed down over time and should retain its momentum. Is there any way to disable the effects of atmospheric drag on smoke so that it continues to move for long periods of time? Thanks